# Php+JS+Mysql не работает

Tags: php

Почему когда я вставляю в шаблон не работает а когда заместо " .$row['name'] . " вставляю город Аксай, все работает

```html
<?php
require 'connect.php';
mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' );
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
do
{
 printf ("<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(function(){ 
$('#mydiv').text('Номер телефона: ' + 
($('#cp_id_626').text().indexOf('" .$row['name'] . "') != -1 ? '".$row['email'] ."' : '+87879897')); 
});
</script>"
 );
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
         ?>
```

Comment: Ага) не знаю почему не работает(

Comment: мать моя женщина, как же ты его отлаживать будешь, если он у тебя весь такой. Сделай через while. Do - сразу выполняет код, а потом обращается к базе, поэтому и значение не подставиться по идее. **while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) !=false){
 твой код
}**

ну или как то так

Comment: Да это понятно, но выборку по другому не делает(

Comment: Что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Полагаю, что ругается на $ - ведь подключения JQuery либы нет

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$db = new Mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
?>
<?php while($data = $sql->fetch_row()): ?>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(function(){ 
$('#mydiv').text('Номер телефона: ' + 
($('#cp_id_626').text().indexOf('<?php echo $row['name']; ?>') != -1 ? '<?php echo $row['email']; ?>' : '+79526036525')); 
});
</script>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Попробуйте вот так

Comment: Выбору с бд теперь не делает

Comment: Если я снова добавляю значение, работает, как буд-то цикл останавливаеся

Comment: Ну так дампите $data смотрите что в sql находиться. `var_dump(iterator_to_array($sql->fetch_row())` перед `while`.... @ВиталийНосиков

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var_dump' (T_STRING), expecting while (T_WHILE)

Comment: Данный код делает только первую выбору, как сделать, чтобы он все остальные выборки делал?

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что ругается на $ - ведь подключения JQuery либы нет.

**UPDATE**

Есть еще вопросы по тому, что написано в коде. Ведь по тому что написано, у вас выведет результат только последнего элемента т.к. текст будет много кратно перезаписан и + к этому у вас будет n+ блоков `<script></script>`. Я бы предложил вынести `script` блоки вне цикла, а внутри цикла сначала сделать большую строку, разделенную например `\n` между записями. А в конце присвоить это `$("#mytext").html(result);`

**UPDATE2**

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' );
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
// that string we will printf out
$resultStr = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> $(function(){ $('#mydiv').text(\" "; 
do
{
    $resultStr+="Номер телефона: ".$row['name'].",Email: ".$row['email']." \n";
    //Проверку я не добавлял - это уже сам =)
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
$resultStr+=");}); </script>";
printf($resultStr);
         ?>
```

Сорри за мой кривой код, я не phpшник ни разу, но как то так это будет работать чутка проще (желательно чтобы #mydiv по возомжности был как можно больше или вообще textarea - тогда не через .text, а черезе html вставлять можно)

Comment: Самое странно, что если вставлять напрямую через консоль, все работает

Comment: И так тоже не работает jQuery(function(){ 
jQuery('#mydiv').text('Номер телефона: ' + 
(jQuery('#cp_id_626').text().indexOf('" .$row['name'] . "') != -1 ? '".$row['email'] ."' : '+7-951-528-49-30')); 
});

Comment: Смена $ на JQuery тебе ничего не даст, если у тебя нет доступа к JQuery библиотеке внутри данного скрипта. Попробуй добавить этот скрипт прямо в js на сайте (именно js - удали части с $row)- проверь его работу. К тому же я дополнил ответ - мб поможет.

Comment: Да все верно, выполняет только последнюю запись в бд, а можно корректный код?

Comment: Ну я бы сделал как-то так

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ysr4eL8b/ правильно я все сделал?

Comment: Конечно же нет - ты видимо плохо понимаешь что происходит в коде, который написал я. Я просто сделал большую строку , которая содержит код js и именно он будет выведен. Если и добавлять проверку то только внутри js кода, не php.... то что ты добавил на место моего коментария свой код еще раз это немного странно и абсолютно неверно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46682/discussion-between---and-alexoander).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно лучше заменить двойные ковычки на одинарные, в print:
print("test") => print('test')

так как возможно компилятор ругается на $ от JQuery как было написано выше.